# Recently used apps android

Tags: android, android-webview

Can someone give me pointers on how to display a list of recently used apps on the android system.

I intend to obtain this and display from within a web-view. Next step would be for me to figure out how to obtain the app icons to display on the webview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ActivityManager.getRecentTasks(): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRecentTasks(int, int)

Comment: broken in Android L :(